# Shell script to increment count of entries

Tags: shell, shell-script

I want a script which increments the count when the script runs. Basically I want to send an email notification when I find 10 devices down from the same country and scripts run after every down event.

So if I set the counter as 0, the script then updates the value as 1 but next time when the script runs it checks the counter is set to 0 and again shows the value as 1.

I need to save the previous counter value with respect to thee country name as both the values are not fixed. Also there are `n` number of devices belong to `n` number of countries.

Comment: you can also set environment variable if possible eg `export var=1` in the terminal and you can use `var=$((var+1)) export var echo $var` in a file example mailit.sh then when you give source mailit.sh it works as counter

Answer (score 3):

One file/counter per country.

```
#!/bin/bash
#Country name is specified as a comamnd line argument
# ie device_count.sh Brazil
if [[ -z "$1" ]] ; then
   echo "Please specify country name" >&2
   exit 1
fi

#Create a new file per country if one doesn't exist already
COUNTER_FILE=/var/tmp/devices.$1
if [[ -r $COUNTER_FILE ]] ; then
   COUNT=$(<$COUNTER_FILE)
else
   COUNT=0
fi

#Increment counter and save to file 
echo $(( $COUNT += 1 )) > $COUNTER_FILE

#check if we need to send email
if [[ $(( $COUNT % 10 )) -eq 0 ]] ; then
   #We have reached 10 - we need to send an email
   echo "BLAH BLAH BLAH " | mailx -s "reached 10" you@domain.com
fi
```

Comment: Thanks Darkheart... What -eq 0 stands for as I am looking for to reset counter to 0 once it sends an email. Will this help ?

Comment: The '%' (aka 'modulo') will divide the counter by 10 and give the remainer. So, therefore, each time the counter reaches a multiple of ten there will be no remainer (ie 0) and an email will be sent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the country counts to a file before you exit your script as the last thing. 
The next time you run your script, you need to read these values from the same file. Otherwise you can not keep the values in memory variables as each shell script you run, executes a subshell with its own variables and destroys the shell and contents, when it exits.

```
x="$country" 

count=$(cat ${country}) 
#instead of starting from 0 each time, start from the content of this file
#you need to manually create each country file with value 0 in it
#before start using this struct.

for device_count in $x 
do 
count=expr $count + 1 
echo "Country_[$device_count] count $count" 
if [ count -eq 5 ]; 
then 
echo "email to be sent " 
fi 
done 


echo ${count} > ${country} 
#at this point you overwrote the file named as
#the name of country you are working here
```

Comment: Thanks for the reponse but its not clear to me ....Could you please explain on script...for example we have already i dentified country for respective down event now that is the only input ,so if 5 down event from same country... x="$country"
count=0
for device_count in $x
do
count=`expr $count + 1`
echo "Country_[$device_count] count $count" 
if [ count -eq 5 ]; then
echo  "email to be sent " 
fi
done

Comment: Please see above.